# Vmware Ubuntu : UDP Packet transmission issue

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, wireshark, ubuntu-10.04, vmware-player

VMware Version : 4.0.2 build-591240
Runs on : winxp

Vmware configures to Load Ubuntu 10.04.

Problem statement :

Wireshark Running on Ubuntu :

Vmware Linux IP : 192.168.83.1
Win Ip          : 10.67.8.70

Host tartget IP : 10.67.8.40

wireshark displays Packets transmitted from Vmware Ubuntu to target host.
But the target Host receives packet from IP i.e win IP & hence the target host send the response Packet back to winIP .. which is it should send back to Ubuntu.

How can i configure the vmware Linux Port to work as Physical portand succeed in receving Packets.

In short the Vmware packet gets embedded with win IP during transmission. How can this be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Network device of you VM Linux in **Bridge Mode**.

With this, the ip address of your Linux should be 10.67.8.x

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem previously. I could not solve this problem directly either. The main reason is that when you bind local ports in Linux virtual machine, the port number will not be the same as the port on Windows host. So, what I did was that I wrote some code on Windows host and used it as a transfer station to transmit UDPs between the original source and destination. Then, you can specify the local and remote IP addresses and ports in the code on Windows code.